# C++ - Object slicing even after using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, object-slicing

I have a base class Shape, and a derived class Circle which inherits Shape publically:

```
class Circle : public Shape
```

I made a C++ vector of Shape pointers, and I assigned Circle pointers to them. I'd read up a lot on object slicing so expected the code to treat the Circle in the vector as a Circle, not a Shape.

Can anyone point out what's wrong with this, given the output?

```
int main(void) {
vector<Shape*> shapes;

Circle* ncl = new Circle(-8, -8, 0.2f);
shapes.push_back(ncl);

cout << "Expected: " << *ncl << endl;
cout << "Reality: " << *shapes[0] << endl;
}
```

outputs:

```
Expected: Circle is at: -8,-8 and has a radius of: 0.2
Reality: Shape centered at point: -8,-8
```

I have overridden the << operator for both classes out of scope, so I think that's not the problem, but still - here's the code context of my overrides:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Shape& shape) {
    std::cout << "Shape centered at point: " << shape.getX() << "," << shape.getY();
    return stream;
}

inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Circle& circle) {
    std::cout << "Circle is at: " << circle.getX() << "," << circle.getY() << 
        " and has a radius of: " << circle.getR();
    return stream;
}
```

All in all - I want to be able to access my Circle variables properly while they're stored in the Shape vector (with pointers or otherwise).

Comment: Does `Shape` have at least a `virtual ~Shape() {}` destructor?

Comment: It does indeed - so does Circle.

Comment: Overload resolution is not dynamic in C++. You need virtual functions here.

Comment: `*shapes[0]` calls `operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Shape& shape)` as it supposed to. Your expectations are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no slicing involved, it just looks like it.

Overloads are selected at compile time, from the static type as it is known to the compiler.
Since `shapes` is a `vector<Shape*>`, `*shapes[0]` is a `Shape&`, and that overload is chosen.

The common solution is to only write an `operator<<` for the base class, and that in turn calls a virtual function on the object.
This will let the dynamic function dispatch select the function at runtime.

For instance:

```
struct Shape  { virtual ostream& print(ostream& os) const { ... } };
struct Circle { ostream& print(ostream& os) const override { ... } };

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Shape& s) { return s.print(os); }
```

Answer (score 1):

overload resolution is done with static type.

You may use:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Shape& shape) {
    shape.print(stream);
    return stream;
}
```

with `virtual void Shape::print(std::ostream&) const;` to solve your issue.